# AWS Role being assumed not being used for future CLI Commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to assume a role in a docker container but it doesn't seem like the role is sticking. Below is the output of `aws sts assume-role` followed by `aws sts get-caller-identity`

```
jenkins@0d4794bcdd62:~/.aws$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "ABCDEFG1234567:i-01234546789abc",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::555555555555:assumed-role/jenkins-masterRole/i-01234546789abc",
    "Account": "555555555555"
}
jenkins@0d4794bcdd62:~/.aws$ aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::555555555555:role/ec2/CloudFormationRole --role-session-name "test-session-name"
{
    "Credentials": {
        "Expiration": "2019-01-28T16:37:04Z",
        "SessionToken": "[redacted]",
        "AccessKeyId": "[redacted]",
        "SecretAccessKey": "[redacted]"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "[redacted]:test-session-name",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::5555555555555:assumed-role/CloudFormationRole/test-session-name"
    }
}
jenkins@0d4794bcdd62:~/.aws$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "Account": "555555555555",
    "UserId": "ABCDEFG1234567:i-01234546789abc",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::555555555555:assumed-role/jenkins-masterRole/i-01234546789abc"
}
```

As you can see, the aws sts-assume role is working, but it doesn't seem like it is being applied. Below are the contents of my ~/.aws/config file

```
jenkins@0d4794bcdd62:~/.aws$ cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = us-east-1
```

I don't have any AWS CLI environment variables set except for `AWS_CONFIG_FILE=~/.aws/config`. Which I originally wasn't set, but I did that while testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `assume-role` is not going to change the configuration of the AWS CLI.  AWS CLI is using the credentials stored in `~/.aws/credentials` to make the calls.  The ones returned by `assume-role` are not copied automatically to AWS CLI configuration file, they are just displayed on your screen.

So, one naive way to solve your problem, would be to copy / paste the access key, secret key and session id to `~/.aws/credentials`  Of course, this would not scale, nor be convenient.  There is a better way.

You can configure a profile in the CLI to use the role you want.  Assuming that your base identity has permission to assume the role (which you do as per your call to assume-role in your question)

This is how I configured my `~/.aws/config` file to get temporary access to my personal account, from my work account.  Of course the same technique also works within the same account.

```
[default]
region=eu-west-1

[profile perso]
region=eu-west-1
role_arn=arn:aws:iam::[redacted]:role/admin
source_profile=default
```

The role ARN is the role you want to assume in the target account.

then you can simply type :

`aws --profile perso s3 ls`

to switch role.

Comment: Ahh, does Boto3 then change your credentials file then? I feel like I have done the assume role in Python, and I haven't had to do anything else

Comment: @Loaf No, boto3 doesn't change your credentials file. If you write Python code using boto3 and you explicitly call assume_role() within your code then the call returns you a set of credentials that you can use to make subsequent API calls.

Comment: All our SDKs have some intelligence in their AWSCredentialProviderObject shared by the global AWS object.  The services object know how to get an access key/secret key from there.  The CognitoCredentialsProviders for example interact with Cognito SSO.  You can read more about Boto3 CredentialsProvider at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html  Note that Boto3 can read the role_arn construct in ~/.aws/config described above.

Comment: You can rely on the `AWS_` environment variables to be able to assume role without even touching configuration files, e.g. checkout the `bash-my-aws` project for an example - https://github.com/bash-my-universe/bash-my-aws/blob/master/lib/sts-functions

Comment: I m afraid this is not always the case : it depends where your code is running.  These environment variables will not appear magically.  If these are available for you in your runtime, something has to set them up (maybe you configured that in your `~/.profile`) but this is not the default in EC2, ECS or Lambda.  We do not recommend passing sensitive information in environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

You can also (ab)use the `--query` option to generate environment variable assignments for the temporary role credentials, like this:

```sh
$ roleSessionName=my-example-session

$ arnOfRoleToAssume=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/demo 

$ assumeRoleEnv=$(aws sts assume-role \
            --role-session-name="$roleSessionName" \
            --role-arn="$arnOfRoleToAssume"\
            --output text \
            --query='Credentials.[
              join(`=`, [`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, AccessKeyId]),
              join(`=`, [`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, SecretAccessKey]),
              join(`=`, [`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, SessionToken])
          ]')

$ eval "export $assumeRoleEnv"

$ aws sts get-caller-identity # this and further aws calls use the assumed role
```

One advantage of this is not having to mess with shared config/credentials. For example, that's why I chose this approach in [awscli-with-assume-role (Docker image)](https://github.com/sgreben/docker-awscli-with-assume-role).